# Roslyn features/patterns branch (C# 7) - How to enable the experimental language features

Tags: c#, roslyn, c#-7.0

I want to experiment with the potential C# 7 future language features.

I have a virtual machine into which I have downloaded the Roslyn codebase (features/patterns branch) and built as described on Roslyn's github here: [Building and Testing on Windows](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/contributing/Building,%20Debugging,%20and%20Testing%20on%20Windows.md).

I can successfully fire up a new experimental instance of Visual Studio (set VisualStudioSetup as the startup project and run).

When I try out the new language features (pattern matching and local functions) I get an error in the editor as a squiggly and also error when I build:

[image: Pattern matching error squiggly]

[image: Local function error squiggly]

> Error CS8058  Feature 'local functions' is experimental and
>   unsupported; use '/features:localFunctions' to enable.
>
> Error CS8058  Feature 'pattern matching' is experimental and
>   unsupported; use '/features:patterns' to enable.

Where do I put these options?

I tried adding it to the command line arguments, but I get an error.

[image: Roslyn Args]

[image: Roslyn Args Error]

Comment: I just found this: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7509 Unable to enable experimental language features through project files. Same issue as mine. I wonder how the Roslyn team tries out the new language features then?

Comment: You cannot pass the flag to devenv.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski how would I do this with VS 15.8 for the latest Roslyn feature branches like async streams? I'm building and then running the VisualStudio.Setup project, which works fine for nullable types because I know from the preview wiki to include `[module: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NonNullTypes]` But not sure how to enable features from other branches.

Comment: @BenHall: it varies feature to feature, and often requires setting /langversion:8. You're probably best off asking this on GitHub by filing a bug or asking in Gitter.

Answer (score 5):

This is [bug 7812](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7812) that I haven't fixed yet. Sorry.

Internally, the compiler team mostly just tests things through unit tests or the command line compiler; if we *really* need to test the IDE we just delete the check that's passing in the feature flag.

Comment: In my defense, I was going to start fixing this today. :-)

Comment: I found a way to enable the new language features (see my own answer), so don't sweat. As a side-effect I learned a lot in the process. It's amazing!

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, I haven't done R&D with the said code you have downloaded.

**But in Visual Studio '15' preview (announced on 30 March 2016) I have fixed this very easily.** It might help other people.

I was getting the error

*Error  CS8058  Feature 'local functions' is experimental and unsupported; use '/features:localFunctions' to enable.*

To fix this select your project name and right click >> Properties Window >> Build and then
add the below two options in "Conditional Compilation symbols" text box  **__DEMO__,__DEMO_EXPERIMENTAL__**

[image]

click on save button to Save it. Now build your application and your build will be succeeded.

Even though at my end if I add any one of the **__DEMO__ & __DEMO_EXPERIMENTAL__** then it is working fine.

Comment: It may not work with Visual Studio 2015, C# 7 was introduced with Visual Studio 2017.

Please do not be confused with Visual Studio Product name and it's version.

Visual Studio 15.x refers to Visual Studio 2017. The latest Version of Visual Studio 2017 is Visual Studio 15.6 which supports C# 7, C# 7.1 and C# 7.2 as well.

Comment: To understand more about versioning please refer the below link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/visual-studio-15-preview-first-look-C-Sharp-7/

Answer (score 3):

I found way to enable the new language features.

By tracing the code I found where the feature check is made (function IsFeatureEnabled) and changed it to always return true.

Then I rebuilt from the command line as before. And after that the new language features are enabled when I fire up the experimental Visual Studio instance.

BEFORE:

[image: Feature Breakpoint]

AFTER:

```
internal bool IsFeatureEnabled(MessageID feature)
{
    // Force all demo features:
    return true;

    // in "demo" mode enable all language features.
    if (PreprocessorSymbols.Contains("__DEMO__"))
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what we've done internally for some demos too. :-)